# Angular UI nested State template is not loading

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Index.html

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="testApp">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="Shortcut Icon" type="image/ico" href="img/favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendor.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.css">
</head>
<body id="wrap">
<div ui-view></div>
<script src="js/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
"use strict";
var TestApp = angular.module("testApp",["ui.router"])
    .config(["$urlRouterProvider","$stateProvider",function(a,b) {
    a.otherwise("test", {
        url: "/test",
        title: "Test",
        template:"<p>Test</p>"
    })
}]);
```

Here is My directory Structure
     testApp
         JS --> app.js
         index.html

Please Correct My Code

Answer (score 0):

The UI-Router is about states. So we have to call  `$stateProvider.state()` to define state(s). The `$urlRouterProvider` method `.otherwise()` should server for default navigation - if url does not match to registered state:

```
.config(["$urlRouterProvider","$stateProvider"
,function($urlRouterProvider,$stateProvider) {

  // instead of this
  a.otherwise("test", {
  // we need to call .state
  $stateProvider.state("test", {
    url: "/test",
    title: "Test",
    template:"<p>Test</p>"
  })

  // and also some defaults
  // but not state name 'test', it should be url '/test'
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/test")
```

Comment: Bingo and OP Plunker for the same is here http://plnkr.co/edit/YnyG0vrZEd8bDI5pbJwS?p=preview